# Is a constant sequence contractive?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

A sequence $\{ a_n \}$ is said to be contractive if $\exists\,\, r\in (0,1)$ s.t.
$$ |a_{n+2} - a_{n+1}|\,\,\le \,\, r|a_{n+1} - a_{n}| \;\;\;\;\;\;\,\, \forall\;\;n\,\in \mathbb N $$
If $\{ a_n \}$  is a constant sequence we can deduce that
$$ |a_{n+2} - a_{n+1}|\,\,= \,\,|a_{n+1} - a_{n}| = 0 \;\;\;\;\;\;\,\, \forall\;\;n\,\in \mathbb N $$
and thus a constant sequence is not contractive. But on the other hand
$$ \because\,\,\,\ |a_{n+2} - a_{n+1}|\,\,= \,\,|a_{n+1} - a_{n}| = 0 \;\;\;\;\;\;\,\, \forall\;\;n\,\in \mathbb N $$
$\therefore$  we can say that for any $ r\in (0,1)$,
$$ |a_{n+2} - a_{n+1}|\,\,= \,\, r|a_{n+1} - a_{n}| \;\;\;\;\;\;\,\, \forall\;\;n\,\in \mathbb N $$
and thus a constant sequence is contractive. So I'm sought off reaching two contradictory conclusion from the same definition.

Comment: Check your definition, it cannot be correct. Using that definition, all sequences would be contractive.

Comment: Moreover, even with your wrong definition, your reasoning asserting "thus a constant sequence is not contractive" is flawed.

Comment: @Pierre Carre Thanks for pointing that out. Fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper definition of a contractive sequence is that there is a constant $0 \leq r < 1$ such that
$$
|a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}| \leq r |a_{n+1}- a_n|
$$

This inequality is in fact satisfied by a constant sequence. This definition is motivated by the fixed point method, where a solution of the equation $x=g(x)$ is approximated by the sequence $x_{n+1} = g(x_n)$. If you think of the contractivity of $g$, rather than the contractivity of the sequence, things may seem more natural.

Answer (score 1):

You gave the wrong definition. A sequence $(a_n)$ is contractive if $$\exists r \in (0,1)\  \text{s.t.} |a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}|\leq r\ |a_{n+1}-a_{n}| $$.
For a constant sequence $$|a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}| = |a_{n+1}-a_{n}| = 0$$
Since $ 0\leq 0$, we can conclude that a constant sequence is contractive.